# how to settimeout in flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, setinterval

what is the setTimeout function in Flex 4?

I tried the old methods like setTimeout () or setInterval but not working, not found any web references as well, anyone know? Thank you all

Comment: some piece of code will do no harm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [flash.utils.Timer](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Timer.html) class for `setTimeout`, `setInterval` etc.

```
//first parameter is delay in milliseconds, 
//second one is number of repetitions required - 
//use zero for infinite repetition

var timer:Timer = new Timer(100, 4);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimerTick);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerDone);
function onTimerTick(e:TimerEvent):void
{
   var timer:Timer = Timer(e.target);
   trace(timer.delay * timer.currentCount + " milliseconds passed");
}
function onTimerDone(e:TimerEvent):void
{
   trace("Timer complete");
}
```